# C++ vector.push_back crashes after pointer definition

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault, push-back

my C++ compiler behaves very weird.

My vector is defined globally:

```
vector<int> values;
```

This does not cause any error:

```
void locate( int r, int s, bool newCheck, int from = 0 ){

static int A = 255;
static int U = 1;
static int D = 2;
static int R = 3;
static int L = 4;

values.push_back(0);

kocka *temp;
*temp = pole[r][s];    

values.push_back(1);

.........................
```

But, this causes an error Segmentation Fault:

```
void locate( int r, int s, bool newCheck, int from = 0 ){

static int A = 255;
static int U = 1;
static int D = 2;
static int R = 3;
static int L = 4;

//values.push_back(0);

kocka *temp;
*temp = pole[r][s];    

values.push_back(1);

...........................
```

Compiled with g++ -O2 -std=c++11
Do you have any idea why it might be behaving this strange way? Thx

Comment: *my C++ compiler behaves very weird.* - This should be pretty much the last thing you go to for what is at fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`temp` is never initialized to anything, so when you assign to it via `*temp = pole[r][s]`, you get undefined behavior, as your trying to write to some random memory location. Initialize `temp` to a sensible value.

Comment: thx, writing kocka *temp;temp = &pole[r][s]; solved my probled :)

Comment: @Milos9304 : Why are you using pointers at all? Wouldn't `kocka& temp = pole[r][s];` be more sensible?